# Changing default ownership for files created by a user

Tags: permissions, unix, file-permissions, scp

I gave user "jdoe" access to SCP files onto a Unix server hosting Wordpress.

Files this user creates within the `/var/www/Wordpress` folder (and subfolders) need to be owned by `www-data` or at least the `www-data` group.

Is there a way to alter the "jdoe" account profile to make this so?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable static group setting by setting set-GID bit on a directory. If `/var/www/Wordpress` is owned by `www-data` user and `www-data` group, you can make any files created under such directory (no matter by which user), have `www-data` group owner:

```
$ chmod g+s /var/www/Wordpress
```

The set-GID bit in the directory will make new files/folders use same group as `/var/www/Wordpress` has.

Comment: For clarification the sticky-bit IS NOT the 's' bit.  In the case/answer mentioned here this is the 'set-gid' bit!  Please use the appropriate terminology here.

Comment: could you offer an edit so I do not get it more wrong? :)

Comment: you got it....by the way setting the SET-UID bit on a directory does NOT change set the file owner.

Comment: okay, I admit I never used it for user, but assumed it will work same way.  Thank you!